# Question about exponential $2^{(x+3)^{(x+2)}} = 4^{x+2}$

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, roots, real-numbers

I have a problem with this equation:

[image: equation]
!
I manage to find the first solution, which is x =-1 but it seems that there is another solution, which is x ≈ -1.19896. How do we do this, I can't seem to find any thread about solving exponential equation where the base is a variable itself.

Thank you!

Comment: `2^{stuff^{more_stuff}}`

Comment: Not entirely sure if this will be helpful, but $4^{x+2}=2^{2(x+2)}$

Comment: i fixed the title for you, too. it will be visible to you when a mod approves it.

Comment: Problems of this form are usually tackled using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1), though since this is beyond the form $a^x=bx+c$, it is most likely the non-trivial has no closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @SimpleArt raises a good point. what sort of class is this for?

Comment: It is for my pre-calculus class. However, when I graph the 2 functions, I'm sure there is 2 intersections, however, I can't seem to find the other point of intersection.

Comment: Title doesn't match scanned problem—I assume the text is correct and the title is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am sorry for the typo.

Comment: @YouXiaoRuan According to the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), non-trivial answers are transcendental.

Comment: To expand, you have a few cases.  If $x$ is rational, it will be trivial $(x=-1)$.  If $x$ is irrational but algebraic, we get contradiction.  Thus, $x$ must be transcendental.  This narrows the solution down to some 'it can't be simple at all', and if we assume all constants are integers combined with operations, we must have [transcendental functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function) in here.  Basically, if don't use special constants like $\pi$, we must get extremely complicated.

Comment: $(x+3)^{x+2}=2x+4$ has one root at $x=-1$ and another at $x\doteq-1.1989575$. Not sure there is any simple closed form for this second solution.

Comment: Maybe it is “engineered” from two different equations which do have a closed form like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782981/an-impossible-closed-form-solution-to-xx-3-2x-3-2x-3/4783907#4783907). However, this question has a photo link broken and is not the most detailed

Answer (score 0):

The values $x+2=1$ and $x+3=2$ are compatible giving the apparent equality $2^2=4$ hence $x=-1$ is a solution.

Taking into account the convexity of the exponential function ($(x+3)^{x+2}=e^{(x+2)(\ln(x+3)}$), if a line passing through a point on the curve is not 
tangent to the curve then this line cuts the curve in another point. We search for another point distinct of $(-1,2)$.

We have clearly the equivalent equation $$(x+3)^{x+2}=2(x+2)$$
Make $$\begin{cases}f(x)= (x+3)^{x+2}\\g(x)=2x+4\end{cases}$$
One has $$f\space’(x)= (x+3)^{x+1}(x+2+(x+3)\ln (x+3))$$ and it is apparent both that $ f\space’(-2)=0$ (*which certainly corresponds to a minimum because of the convexity*) and that $y=2x+4$  is not tangent to the curve. It follows there is a second solution so one has to solve a transcendental equation. We calculate approximations as usual.
$$\begin{cases}f(-1)=g(-1)=2\\f(-1.1)=1.9^{0.9}\approx 1.78187\text{ and }g(-1.1)=1.8\\f(-1.2)=1.8^{0.8}\approx 1.60036\text{ and }g(-1.2)=1.6\end{cases}$$ since $$f(-1.1)\lt g(-1.1)\text { and }\space f(-1.2)\gt g(-1.2)$$  there is a point solution $x_0$ such that $$-1.2\lt x_0\lt-1.1$$ this is an small interval, of length $0.1$, that can be narrowed more and more by successive approximations. We stop here saying that the solution $x_0\approx -1.19896$ given by the O.P. can be approximated this way.

Comment: Did you use bijection?  I would up vote if you used a better approximation method.

Comment: Believe it or not, dear friend, I am not interested in up votes so this reply does not point in the direction of looking for: if you have the other solution in an small open interval $I$ then each approximation narrows more and more  $I$ in such a way that you can take as plausible approximation one of the borders obtained (say, at the third or fourth  approximation). Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Believe it or not, dear friend, I ***am*** interested in upvoting you, but the method you are using to calculate your answer numerically is quite unfavorable.  All I ask is for better methods, like applying Newton's method (hey, you already have the derivative part done).

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments and answer, th problem is to find the zero of function $$f(x)=(x+3)^{(x+2)}-2(x+2)$$
Expanding as a series around $x=-1$ (the known solution), we have
$$f(x)=(2 L-1) (x+1)+\left(L^2+L+1\right) (x+1)^2+$$ $$\frac{1}{12} \left(4 L^3+6 L^2+12
   L+3\right) (x+1)^3+O\left((x+1)^4\right)$$ where $L=\log(2)$.

Solving the quadratic and selecting the closest root
$$x=- \frac{\left(4 L^3+12 L^2+18 L+9\right) -2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{-5 L^4-2 L^3-9 L^2+12 L+6}}{4 L^3+6 L^2+12 L+3 }$$ which is $\color{red}{-1.20203}$.

Adding the next term, which is
$$\frac{1}{24} \left(2 L^4+4 L^3+12 L^2+6 L+5\right)(x+1)^4$$ there is only one real root for the cubic which has been solved **analytically** using the hyperbolic solution. Its numerical value is $\color{red}{-1.19872}$.

Remember that the "exact" solution is $\color{blue}{-1.19896}$