# An (im)possible closed form solution to $x^{x^{-3}}=2^{x^{-3}-2^{x-3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, special-functions, exponentiation

> Solve in real numbers
> $$x^{x^{-3}}=2^{x^{-3}-2^{x-3}}$$

**My attempt**

To be honest this is not an actual attempt, but that is all I could do. That question was shared in a math group. $x^{-3}$ together with $x-3$ is mind blowing. The first thing I did to answer the question was to set up graphics .

[image]

There is exactly one real root and this root appears to be positive. As a result of numerical approximation $x\approx1.28237148900997...$

I could not approach the question algebraically.  The question is beyond my knowledge.  But out of curiosity I tried a lot of rational and irrational numbers, for example $x=\frac{\sqrt {41}}{5}$. I could not find a number matching the number $x\approx 1.2823$

Does the equation have a solution known as a closed form, or can it ?

Answers from all perspectives are appreciated.

Comment: Just in terms of rewriting the equation I see $\left(\frac 2x\right)^{x^{-3}}=2^{2^{x-3}}$.  This does nothing significant immediately except that in real numbers it is clear the new RHS is greater than $1$ giving $2\gt x$ for this result on the LHS...

Comment: @hardmath does the math group have the solution?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ So far no one has been able to come up with a complete solution.

Comment: The mix of $x^{-3}$ and $x-3$ does seem curious. What's the source of the exercise? If it's something circulating on social media, its formatting may have been mangled from iteration to iteration, or it may just be some nonsense "challenge" from someone throwing symbols around. (BTW: The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.282371489&lookup_type=simple) doesn't identify your value $1.28237\ldots$.)

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your perspective. Could the downvotes I received prevent people from seeing the question? In partial answer to your question, yes we can completely trust the question form, there is no possibility of any typo.  But I'm not sure it's not nonsense.  However can we think that the probability of a solution in real numbers for a question written with random symbols would be very low, or not ? Can I avoid downvotes if I add more effort to my question?  Even though I couldn't find a solution I did some things. But I know it won't do any good.

Comment: @hardmath I did not downvote, but in general in this stack participants like to see some *context* to a question. Where and how did this problem arise? "Shared in a math group" is a bit nondescript. Is this a pure challenge posed by someone, or does it have some practical relevance? Is it a problem that was posed in a math olympiad, maybe? The question seems fine as-is with regard to documenting how you attempted to solve it (that is one point where many questions fall short).

Comment: @hardmath: Downvotes don't affect visibility, although they probably de-motivate people from reading. ... Personally, I think you've done okay in presenting a question you're not sure how to approach. As njuffa mentioned, though, you could/should provide a bit more context (in the question body, not just as a comment) about the source/purpose of the question. You commented "[W]e can completely trust the question form". *Why?* Did someone from your math group devise it? If so, then please ask them on my behalf for the intended soln. :) And, yes: Solns to a random equation are highly improbable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

Let $x=2w$:
$$x^{x^{-3}}=2^{x^{-3}-2^{x-3}}\iff-\log_2\left(\frac x2\right)=2^{x-3}x^3\iff -\log_2(w)=4^ww^3$$

and notice the graphs cross at $(w,w)$

[image]

so we set one equal to $w$ and use [Lambert W](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html):

$$w=-\log_2(w)\iff w2^w=1\\\boxed{x=2\frac{\operatorname W(\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}=2e^{-\operatorname W(\ln(2))}}$$

**Equation Derivation**

The solution is not fully rigorous where it says the graphs cross at $(w,w)$, so here is probably how the equation’s creator made it, for a clearer perspective. Start with a transcendental equation and solve for $w$:

$$w2^w=1\implies \color{blue}w=-\log_2(w)$$

Also, square both sides and multiply by $w$ in the starting equation:

$$w2^w=1\iff (w 2^w)^2w=1^2w\iff4^ww^3=\color{blue}w$$

Since the two equations marked in blue both equal $w$, equate them and rearrange:

$$-\log_2(w)=4^ww^3\iff w^{w^{-3}}=2^{-4^w}$$

Finally, substitute $w=\frac x2$:

$$w^{w^{-3}}=2^{-4^w} \iff x^{x^{-3}}=2^{x^{-3}-2^{x-3}}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I do not understand your first attempts

Comment: @hardmath By “first attempts”, do you mean the substitutions and equation rearrangements?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are looking for the zero of function $$f(x)=\log\Big(x^{x^{-3}}\Big)-\log\Big(2^{x^{-3}-2^{x-3}}\Big),$$ you could define the solution to be the infinite limit of the **first** iterate of a Newton-like method of order $n$ starting with
$$x_0=2\log(2)$$ The formulae will be nasty, very long to type but totally explicit.

I give you the very first (for Newton method)
$$x_{(2)}=2 L-\frac{2 L \left(2^{2 L} L^4+\log (L)\right)}{2^{2 L+1} L^6-3   \log (L)+1}\qquad \text{where} \qquad L=\log(2)$$ Computing the next ones and converting them to decimals

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 & \color{red}{1.2}6372070923 & \text{Newton}\\
 3 & \color{red}{1.282}31922203 & \text{Halley}\\
 4 & \color{red}{1.282}45476924 & \text{Householder}\\
 5 & \color{red}{1.28237}340841 & \text{no name}\\
 6 & \color{red}{1.282371}25177 & \text{no name}\\
 7 & \color{red}{1.2823714}7462 & \text{no name}\\     
 \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
 \infty &  \color{red}{1.28237148901}& \text{solution}\\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$